# Issue with SQL Server escape character for SSRS parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, escaping, ssrs-2012

In SSRS I have a parameter of office manager names that is populated by a stored procedure:

```
   SELECT
            MANAGER.office_manager_name
        FROM  (SELECT
                     ISNULL(REPLACE(PRACT_LOC.officemanagername, ',', ''), '*N/A') AS office_manager_name
                     FROM  PRACTICELOCATIONS PRACT_LOC 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                     '*N/A') MANAGER
        ORDER  BY
            MANAGER.office_manager_name
```

The parameter is populated like this:

```
   *N/A, Smith John, Sharp Alex, O'Toole Tom
```

In SQL Server I have another SP that joins the office manager name from a table using a function splitter:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE IP
    (@office_manager_name VARCHAR(4000))
    AS

    Select * from Table A
    where ISNULL(REPLACE(A.officemanagername, ',', ''), '*N/A') IN (SELECT item FROM   DBO.FNSPLIT(@officemanagername, ','))
```

The function splitter code looks like this:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit]
    (
@sInputList VARCHAR(MAX), -- List of delimited items
@sDelimiter VARCHAR(MAX) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
    ) 

    RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(MAX))

   BEGIN

   DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(MAX)

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT
      @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX      (@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
      @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

    IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
    INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
    RETURN

     END
```

The issue I'm having is that any records with office manager Tom O'Toole do not show up in the report if I select All managers from the parameter.  He does show up if I just select O'Toole Tom from the parameter list.  I'm thinking it has to do with the apostrophe in his last name as he is the only manager with an apostrophe.  If this is the case does anyone know how to use an escape character in this code to get O'Toole to populate?

Comment: I removed my answer because I checked your split function and it has no problem. My question now is what your parameter looks like? Is it text parameter allowing multiple values?

Comment: Or it's always one-valued text parameter where comma-separated list can be passed in?

Comment: The parameter is a text parameter that allows multiple values.

Comment: I've tested it with my report that accepts multiple values and SSRS passes that values correctly doubling apostrophe if it's present. So it does not passes the values as 1 string as you wrote, i.e. does not pass '*N/A, Smith John, Sharp Alex, O'Toole Tom' string, but passes '*N/A', 'Smith John', 'Sharp Alex', 'O''Toole Tom'. I suggest you to use SQL Server Profiler to catch the exact text passed to your server. I just cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have permissions to use SQL Server Profiler.  Is there another way to see what exact text is being passed?

Comment: I know this probably isn't the best route to take, but this seems to work: AND (ISNULL(REPLACE(A.officemanagername, ',', ''), '*N/A') IN (SELECT item FROM   DBO.FNSPLIT(@officemanagername, ',')) 
 or ISNULL(REPLACE(A.officemanagername, ',', ''), '*N/A')like 'O''%')

Comment: That is not a way to go, what will you do whene there will be another manager with last name starting with O that is not selected but still will be shown? Can you share in some way your rdl file? I'd substitute your table with mine and see in profiler where is the issue

Comment: Can you share your rdl file? I could substitute your table with mine, all the rest will be the same, the procedure, the function, I just want to know what it passes and why cannot I reproduce it

Comment: Your last code will fail when there will be another manager with last name started with O that is not selected but will be shown. Or when another strange last name will appear

Comment: Ok, I've got it. It has 1 zip file, for now I'll just try to unzip it, tomorrow I'll try to reproduce the issue

Comment: Great, thanks.  I appreciate your help.  Let me know if you need anything else to test this.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue using SQL Server Profiler.
What reporting is sending to server is this:

```
exec rsp_m_initialprocessxxxx @practice_manager=N'*N/A,O''''Toole Tom,Sharp Alex,Smith John'
```

As you can see instead of 2 apostrophes it's sending 4: `O''''Toole Tom`.

When splitting this sting using `DBO.FNSPLIT` you've got `O''Toole Tom` instead of `O'Toole Tom` and this finds no matches in your table.

The workaroud is the following: replace 4 apostrophes with 2 in your stored procedure like this, adding additional variable @practice_manager1:

```
declare @practice_manager1 varchar(4000) = (select replace(@practice_manager, replicate(char(39), 2), replicate(char(39), 1)));

Select * from dbo.A
where ISNULL(REPLACE(A.office_manager_name, ',', ''), '*N/A') IN (SELECT item FROM DBO.FNSPLIT(@practice_manager1, ','));
```

Char(39) is apostrophe, I use its code instead of the symbol for not becoming crazy with '''''

P.S. you are using SSRS 2016, not 2012

**UPDATE1**

> I just tried this but it still doesn't work. It also doesn't work if I
>   just select Tom O'Toole instead of All, which previously worked.

I've tested this code one more time for both cases, here is my repro:

```
declare @t table (test_num int, name varchar(4000)); 
insert into @t values (1, 'O''Toole Tom'),
(2, '*N/A,O''''Toole Tom,Sharp Alex,Smith John');

SELECT test_num, name, item 
FROM @t cross apply DBO.FNSPLIT(name, ',');

SELECT test_num, name, item 
FROM @t cross apply DBO.FNSPLIT(replace(name, replicate(char(39), 2), replicate(char(39), 1)), ',');
```

I've inserted 2 strings for both cases and applied `DBO.FNSPLIT` to that strings directly and after making a `replace`, the second way worked in both cases:

[image]

**UPDATE2**

How to find the **first** parameter passed to stored procedure.

First of all ALTER your procedure, that will invalidate the old plan.
Then run it from SSRS with the problematic parameter. This parameter will be sniffed as it's the first execution. Then you can see it as `ParameterCompiledValue` graphically or in xml of your procedure plan.

Here is the code to grab the proc's plan from the cache:

```
select qp.query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps
     cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ps.plan_handle) qp
where object_id = object_id('dbo.sp_test'); -- put here your sp name
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by what you're suggesting.  Are you suggesting to manually insert a double apostrophe by O'Toole's name?  I wouldn't be able to do that as the manager names are dynamic.

Comment: I tried using the function you supplied but I get an error "invalid object name 'dbo.Nums'.

Comment: @jackstraw22 I've found the issue this morning and updated my answer. The problem was "inverse" to what we was thinking about, SSRS adds too many apostrophes when sending the string to SQL Server

Comment: @sepupic--I just tried this but it still doesn't work.  It also doesn't work if I just select Tom O'Toole instead of All, which previously worked.  I'm going to play around with your code a bit.

Comment: It's very strange, I tested this code with your data and it worked, at least in SSRS 2012. Could it be changed in 2016, the way it passes parameters?

Comment: Well, this may be one reason it's not working.  I checked today and all the records with Tom O'Toole's name are gone.  Looks like something may have changed with the data.  LOL.  I'll see if O'Toole shows up in any other reports.

Comment: Okay, I created a small test version of another report using your code and it seems to work!  Do you know how I can see what string is being passed from SSRS?  I don't have permissions to use SQL Profiler.  I was able to do this at my last company because we used C# and I could step through the code, but here it's straight SSRS to SQL Server.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You must have ALTER TRACE permission to see it

Comment: You can check your server level permissions executing select * from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'server')

Comment: Another way to get what it passes to server is to grab the execution plan for this procedure from the plan cache, you can alter your proc and execute it from SSRS, it will be the first execution and the parameter will be sniffed and you'll be able to see it in the plan. You need VIEW SERVER STATE permission to do this, if you have this permission and you are interested in, let me know, I'll give you the query for taking the plan out of cache

Comment: Apparently the only permissions I have are Connect SQL and View Any Database.  I just put a request in to get SQL Server Profiler permissions.  But at home I have my own personal test environment, so I would like you to show me how to take the plan out of the cache.  It's always good to know things like that.  Thanks.

Comment: At home you can use Profiler as well it is the easiest way to see what enter to the server. It's included even in Express Edition, not as a tool apart but as the part of SSMS. Now I want to test what you said before: when the input has a double quotes instead of 4 of them, if my code will fail. I did non tested this case at work

Comment: @jackstraw22 I updated my answer with the code that finds the stored procedure plan and the first parameters passed to the procedure

Comment: @sepupic--that's great stuff, thanks.  I'll have to play around with this at home to better understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "'" symbol in the Ton's name, try to add the code the replace bellow

```
  REPLACE(@officemanagername,'''','''''')

----
CREATE PROCEDURE ##IP
    (@office_manager_name VARCHAR(4000))
    AS

    Select * from Table A
    where ISNULL(REPLACE(A.officemanagername, ',', ''), '*N/A') IN (SELECT item FROM   DBO.FNSPLIT(REPLACE(@officemanagername,'''',''''''), ','))
```

Comment: @jackstraw22, can you insert the code of DBO.FNSPLIT?

Comment: @jackstraw22 I did some tests in my environment, and I can find any problem with your logic. Please, try to verify if the Tom register does not have any extra space or if in the database the ' is the ASCII char 39.

Comment: @Mauricio--if I hard code it like this it works: AND (ISNULL(REPLACE(A.officemanagername, ',', ''), '*N/A') IN (SELECT item FROM   DBO.FNSPLIT(@officemanagername, ',')) 
        or ISNULL(REPLACE(A.officemanagername, ',', ''), '*N/A') = O''Toole Tom').  But none of the other methods work.  I know it's horrible practice to hard code, but otherwise I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my stored procedure.

Reducing quotes in my procedure `REPLACE(@param,'''','''''')` works. But, calling my procedure outside of SSRS won't work for real 2 single quotes.

There is a better solution. You can **join report parameters before passing** them to your procedure:

```
Join(Parameters!Value.Value, ",")
```